# WCF configuration metadata exchange and help page endpoint

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I had add help page endpoint as in an  [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and my metadata exchange endpoint stop work. Here exception details when i try to see metadata http://imgur.com/delete/HYe9c9OocABgxOj Without it all works great but i need to attach help page

```
<system.serviceModel>       
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehaviors" name="GoalTracker.WcfRestService.Service1">
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="GoalTracker.WcfRestService.IService1" />

            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="GoalTracker.WcfRestService.IService1" />
            <endpoint address="Help" kind="webHttpEndpoint"
                behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior"
                contract="GoalTracker.WcfRestService.IService1" />
        </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehaviors">
                <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"
                              httpHelpPageEnabled="True"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>          
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RESTEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>       
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract on your `mex` endpoint should be `IMetadataExchange` However, I am not sure why you need `mex` endpoint as your service is REST based.

By setting `helpEnabled="true"` in the endpoint behavior, the help page will be automatically enabled. You don't need to add another endpoint with `"Help"` address. Please remove that endpoint.

Set the  `kind="webHttpEndpoint"` and `behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior"` on the main endpoint where `address=""`.

So it should look like this:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehaviors" name="GoalTracker.WcfRestService.Service1">

        <endpoint address="" kind="webHttpEndpoint"
            behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior"
            contract="GoalTracker.WcfRestService.IService1" />

</service>
```

Comment: I have only IService1 contract there discribed my API's

Comment: right - however, if you expose a `mex` endpoint with `mexHttpBinding` it should have `IMetadataExchange` as the contract. This is build-in contract within WCF. Alternatively, if you don't want the Mex endpoint - REST services normally don't need one - you can remove that endpoint.

Comment: when i expose a mex endpoint with mexHttpBinding, IMetadataExchange it's does not change behavior. I can delete help page endpoint and mex  working with IMetadataExchange too as with IService1. I see that it dont matter for him. But it still not resolve my problem. i can't use help and mex endpoints both

Comment: yes, it's helps. I did the same 1 hour ago, and had not see your updated answer )) But anyway thanks